# DataFrame of Dates into sequential dates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to turn a dataframe as follows into a data frame of sequential dates.

```
Date
01/25/1995
01/20/1995
01/20/1995
01/23/1995
```

into

```
Date        Value    Cumsum
01/20/1995    2         2
01/21/1995    0         2
01/22/1995    0         2
01/23/1995    1         3
01/24/1995    0         3
01/25/1995    1         4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df_out = df.assign(Value=1).set_index('Date').resample('D').asfreq().fillna(0)
df_out = df_out.assign(Cumsum=df_out['Value'].cumsum())
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
            Value  Cumsum
Date                     
1995-01-20    1.0     1.0
1995-01-21    0.0     1.0
1995-01-22    0.0     1.0
1995-01-23    1.0     2.0
1995-01-24    0.0     2.0
1995-01-25    1.0     3.0
```

Comment: `df.resample('D', on='Date').count().rename(columns={'Date':'Value'})`

Comment: yep, even better :)